# Javascript > form results to "remember" user > avoid showing form twice

Tags: javascript

I have a java script form in a website, that outputs some results -a silly simple mathematical operation or subtraction of dates.

I need these results to "remember" the visit so the div and the results
show when the user re-loads the page.

How can I achieve this?? It's my first time with facing a situation like this...

Note: its not a logged user!! but a non-logged visit..

http://goo.gl/OHQmpb

Comment: store it in `local storage` or in simple,  create `cookies` and make use of it..  And thereby update it whenever your load it

Comment: WHAT IS Better??? and easier to implement?

Comment: since it fully for client-side, then html5 local storage is the best.  I have explained it in answer, have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`.

Store the values in it by specifiying a key:

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value');
```

And, you can get the value by:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML5 Web storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is the best option in your case.

Exact definition:

> So what is HTML5 Storage? Simply put, **it’s a way for web pages to
>   store named key/value pairs locally, within the client web browser**.
>   Like cookies, *this data persists even after you navigate away from the
>   web site, close your browser tab, exit your browser, or what have you.*
>   *Unlike cookies, this data is never transmitted to the remote web
>   server (unless you go out of your way to send it manually).*

With HTML5, web pages can store data locally within the user's browser.

```
// Store it in object
localStorage.setItem("form attributes", "form values");
// Retrieve from object
localStorage.getItem("form attributes");
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML5 Local Storage aka Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) can store values without maintaining a server side session. See this example:

```
function calculate(){
    return 'some value';
}

window.onload = function(){

    // submit handler for the form, store in local storage
    document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function(){
        localStorage.setItem('calcResult', calculate());
        return false;
    };

    // load the value if present
    var result = localStorage.getItem('calcResult');
    if(result != null){
        // show in div
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```